# Can I autoconfigure both interfaces as slaac (accept_ra 1) on a non-router device?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ipv6

Need clarification to the following statement

Also, due to restrictions in the IPv6 specification, it is not recommended to autoconfigure a host with multiple external interfaces (like 2 ethernet interfaces).

from page
https://www.netbsd.org/docs/network/ipv6/

Noting the statement is for BSD kernel, my question is for Linux, not sure if is even accurate or if it applies to latest kernels.

Here is my question.

I have a non router host, two interfaces, eth0, eth1, set accept_ra to 1 on both.
The routing table ends up with two default link-local routes.

default via fe80::b60c:25ff:fee0:8011 dev eth1 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1726sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
default via fe80::b60c:25ff:fee0:8011 dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1787sec hoplimit 64 pref medium

Is this going to work, I am concerned about having two default routes, and if the statement above still applies.
The statement seems to indicate that you cannot have host, two interfaces, set stateless (slaac) on ipv6.

The kernel doesn't complain about setting ipv6 slaac autoconfiguration on both interfaces.
Should I assume that if the kernel doesn’t complain about autoconfiguration on both interfaces, this kernel allows it?
I think there is some packet filtering on the kernel side, not sure how it works in this situation.

Researched, but unable to figure out how the kernel handles the two default routes, they both use metric 1024, so it is going to do some balancing.

fe80::b60c:25ff:fee0:8011 is the router address on local subnet.
So in this case is the same router link-local address, but in theory, the two interfaces could connect to subnets with different routers.

Thank you